# Dividing numbers with exponents and powers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can someone please help me simplify the below problem. I am trying to help my niece

$${24C^4 \over 4C^{12}}$$

I believe that the simplified answer is $6/C^8$ because $4$ goes into $24$ $6$ times and $6$ remains as the numerator. Also, you need to subtract $4$ from $C^4$ which becomes $1$ and subtract $4$ from $C^{12}$ and it equals $C^8$.  however my niece thinks it is: $1/(6C^8)$. what is the correct answer?

Comment: You are correct. Do you know why your niece thinks it's $1/C^8$? You could use the communicative property to rewrite it as $24/4 \cdot C^4/C^{12}$ to make it more explicit.

Comment: What is the "communicative property"?

Comment: @NickD I think autocorrect got me. Commutative.

Comment: @AndrewLi She has claimed that her teacher simply says that is the answer. I realize that I could go to the school and speak to the teacher to let her know that she is showing the students wrong, but I decided to drop it lol. I know that I am right so I can sleep in peace now :D

Answer (score 1):

One approach I've used for someone beginning to work with this type of situation is the following, although I'd probably replace it with something similar and simpler, such as $\frac{24C^2}{4C^5},$ to actually illustrate the idea.

$$ \frac{24C^4}{4C^{12}} \; = \; \frac{24 \cdot C^4}{4 \cdot C^{12}} \; = \; \frac{24}{4} \cdot \frac{C^4}{C^{12}} $$

$$ = \; \; \frac{24}{4} \cdot \frac{C \cdot C \cdot C \cdot C \cdot 1 \cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 1}{C \cdot C \cdot C \cdot C \cdot C \cdot C \cdot C \cdot C \cdot C \cdot C \cdot C \cdot C} $$

$$ = \;\; \frac{24}{4} \cdot \frac{C}{C} \cdot \frac{C}{C} \cdot \frac{C}{C} \cdot \frac{C}{C} \cdot \frac{1}{C} \cdot \frac{1}{C} \cdot \frac{1}{C} \cdot \frac{1}{C} \cdot \frac{1}{C} \cdot \frac{1}{C} \cdot \frac{1}{C} \cdot \frac{1}{C}   $$

$$  = \;\; \frac{6}{1} \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot \frac{1}{C} \cdot \frac{1}{C} \cdot \frac{1}{C} \cdot \frac{1}{C} \cdot \frac{1}{C} \cdot \frac{1}{C} \cdot \frac{1}{C} \cdot \frac{1}{C} $$

$$   = \;\; \frac{6}{1} \cdot \frac{1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 }{C \cdot C \cdot C \cdot C \cdot C \cdot C \cdot C \cdot C}$$

$$ = \;\; \frac{6}{1} \cdot \frac{1}{C^8} \;\; = \;\; \frac{6}{C^8}   $$

What you want to do is go over several elaborate expansions like this and *let the student* discover the shortcuts that can be taken, and then when the student is comfortable with simple things like this (integer times a letter to a positive integer power, divided by an integer times a letter to a positive integer power), begin branching out to things like $\frac{24x^3y^5}{6x^2y^8}.$ All this should not take more than 5 to 15 minutes, after which you can begin talking about the relevance of the laws of exponents to the shortcuts the student has observed, as well as mixing in things like $C^3 \cdot C^4 = (CCC)\cdot (CCCC) = CCCCCCC = C^{3+4}$ $(3\;C$'s followed by $4\;C$'s is $7\;C$'s), if this had not already been done at some previous time.

Comment: +1 for Exceptional effort from exceptional person.

Comment: Really great way to explain. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct. The simplified answer is $\frac{6}{C^8}$.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you!